# yarn install error. Integrity check failed for "micromatch"

Tags: command-line-interface, yarnpkg

please help!

I try deleting the entire node_modules directory and running yarn install again to reinstall all packages. But, when i running yarn install, this is what happen. What is the meaning of this?

I already try to update to the latest version of EAS CLI and Expo CLI. But, it still not working.

I currently using `expo-cli 5.3.0`

error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/micromatch/-/micromatch-4.0.5.tgz: Integrity check failed for "micromatch" (computed integrity doesn't match our records, got "sha512-DMy+ERcEW2q8Z2Po+WNXuw3c5YaUSFjAO5GsJqfEl7UjvtIuFKO6ZrKvcItdy98dwFI2N1tg3zNIdKaQT+aNdA== sha1-vImZp8u/d83InxMvbkZwUbSQkMY=")

[image]

reinstall all packages

Comment: hi! did you figure it out? i have the same error